# Change size of a saved plot or image (post-processing)

Tags: plotting, size

I have many plots (that take a long time to run) and each is saved to a variable name. For simplicity, say one was:

```
m = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

If I call for the plot

```
m
```

it will be presented as it should be, with `ImageSize` 600. I can click and drag the corners to change the size of the plot (instantaneously, so I know mathematica is not re-computing the plot, but simply adjusting the output image size continuously).

Therefore, what I wish to accomplish must be possible to do, but I don't know how to instruct mathematica to do it.

What I want is a command, something similar to, say

```
m /. ImageSize -> 200
```

etc. that can present m with a new, prescribed size, rather than manually sliding it to a new size, and certainly without having to re-compute the code that produced the saved plot. Help?

Comment: Or just `Show[m, ImageSize -> 200]`

Comment: Steve, @Öskå is the correct answer. While using the rule method works, it depends on the internal structure of `Graphics` to do so. Using `Show` does not. Well, in the sense that you no longer have to worry about it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks, Show should work for me.

Comment: `# /. (ImageSize -> (ImageSize /. Last@#)) -> (ImageSize -> 200) &[m]` _directly_ replaces the previously defined size definition in your case, as `FullForm` will demonstrate you.

Comment: Another way: `Image[m, ImageSize -> 200]`.

Answer (score 3):

There are two straight-forward ways of doing this. The first, as mentioned in the comments by `Oska` is

```
Show[m, ImageSize -> 200]
```

As mentioned by `Guess Who It Is` in a comment, this is the more idiomatic way of doing things, as this is exactly what `Show` is for. To understand what this does, do

```
Last@Normal@m
```

and

```
Last@Normal@Show[m, ImageSize -> 200]
```

Both have the option `ImageSize -> 600` buried in the list of `Options`, but the second has `ImageSize -> 200` prepended to the list. `Plot` uses the first instance of an option, so the new `ImageSize` overrides the original.

---

The second, which uses a replacement rule similar to one in a comment by `UDB`, is

```
mNew = m /. HoldPattern[ImageSize -> _] -> (ImageSize -> 200)
```

This replacement rule find a match for the  pattern `HoldPattern[ImageSize -> _]` and replaces it with the new one. Now, if you do

```
Last@Normal@mNew
```

you will now find `ImageSize -> 200` in the place where `ImageSize -> 600` used to be.

Moral of the second story: it helps to remember that everything in Mathematica is an expression (including graphics), and so parts can be replaced with the relevant replacement rule.

Comment: I'd say `Show[]` is more idiomatic tho; it's precisely the function intended for *post hoc* changes of graphics settings.